# Basic Javascript- HTML button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a button that submits a text input, and have that input show as an alert. Here's my code so far (which shows an alert with "undefined"):

```
<p class="text-right">
 <input id="input" type="text" placeholder= "Your Name">
  <button id="submit" type="submit"> Submit</button>
</p>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.addEventListener("click", function1);

function function1() {
  alert(input.value);
}
```

Comment: `element.value.value` doesn't exist. `alert(input)`. Don't redefine `submit`

Comment: It comes out blank now.

Comment: so then there's nothing in the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.addEventListener("click", function1);
function function1() {
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    alert(input);
}
```

You're alerting `input.value.value`, but you already have the value in the input variable. **EDIT :**

```
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
submit.addEventListener("click", function1);
function function1() {
    alert(input.value);
}
```

Which is declaring the input once, and each time the function is called, you alert it's value.

Comment: But it comes out blank. I don't seem to be able to get that value to show.

Comment: That did it, I was thinking it was a matter of positioning, I'm an absolute beginner, was it a matter of scope?

Comment: No, the variable input was holding the initial value of the input box which is empty, but it's better to just hold the input box in the variable input, and each time the button is clicked, you alert the value. See the last edit, it's better.